# pdf overlay touch in an app

Tags: objective-c, pdf, overlay

i'm looking for pdf overlay feature to be implemented in iOS app, if whether its possible with libs free or even paid to have an touch overlay on PDF page within an app?

what i'm trying to do is i have a map which is train map and i want to have the map as pdf and any touch on station brings up info on each station.

is that posssible or what is other way to go forward open to every opinion!!!

i saw some other questions but none directed like this i.e.

[Overlay Image above Embedded pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028327/overlay-image-above-embedded-pdf)

can any one tell me if its actually possible in objctive C code?

needs to work as offline app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps Static API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to return an image on the map and then convert it to pdf.